# d3.exit().remove() does not work like I expected

Tags: d3.js

I want to delete a line I select. 
I will find the line when I click the line and I will remove the related data with what I select.

So I force to put the data in 'deleteLine' function, however always the second line is deleted. even when I put the data for second line to the data.

I think I don't understand d3 enter delete function. any advice please.

here is fiddle example
https://jsfiddle.net/victoriaVvv/c2pybvmd/90/

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
super(props)
this.drawLine = this.drawLine.bind(this)
this.deletLine = this.deleteLine.bind(this);
this.data = [
{ source : 'a', target:'b', x1 : 0, y1 : 0, x2 : 100, y2 : 100 },
{ source : 'c', target:'d', x1 : 100, y1 : 0, x2 : 200, y2 : 200 }
];

}
    componentDidMount(){
    //this.setSVG();

    this.deleteLine();

    const svg = d3.select('#svg').append('svg')

      .attr("width", '100%').attr("height", 500)
      .attr("style", 'background:#efefef').attr("id","abc");
       //const data = [{ source : 'a', target:'b', x1 : 0, y1 : 0, x2 : 100, y2 : 100 }];

      this.drawLine(this.data);
  }


  drawLine(data){



    const svg = d3.select("#abc");
    console.log(svg)
    const line = svg.selectAll('line').data(data);
            console.log(line)
        line.enter()
        .append('line')
        .attr('stroke', '#000')
        .attr('stroke-width', 3)
        .attr('x1', function(d) {return d.x1})
        .attr('y1', function(d) {return d.y1})
        .attr('x2', function(d) {return d.x2})
        .attr('y2', function(d) {return d.y2})
        //.merge(line)

        line.exit().remove();



  }
  deleteLine() {
    d3.select('body')
    .on('keydown', () => {
            if(d3.event.keyCode === 8){
            // TODO find selected line and will delete the line in the data. 
            // currently this data is hard coded
            this.data = [{ source : 'c', target:'d', x1 : 0, y1 : 0, x2 : 100, y2 : 100 }];
          console.log(2);
          this.drawLine(this.data);
        }

    })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <div id='svg'></div>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [key function](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data). Without a key function,

> the first datum in data is assigned to the first selected element, the second datum to the second selected element, and so on. A key function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, by computing a string identifier for each datum and element.

In your case, the best string is combining `source` and `target`:

```
const line = svg.selectAll('line').data(data, function(d){
    return d.source + d.target;
});
```

Here is the updated JSFiddle, just press <kbd>backspace</kbd>: https://jsfiddle.net/31vfwcjp/1/. By the way, nothing will be changed because your update selection does nothing.